# Qbs Export item not transient

Tags: c++, qt, qbs

I have several projects which share common classes and therefore I’m about to change the project
layout to reflect these dependencies by splitting it into components which are implemented as static libraries.

For now I created one module 'io' which uses an Export block to export its include path. The module is depended upon by 'core'. 'Core' by itself is then depended upon by 'app', nothing special so far.

The documentation of the Export item says that its properties are transitive but I get several errors
from the compiler when compiling app that includes from core cannot be found. Looking at the
compiler statement, the include path exported by io is not listed in the include paths. 
When adding the dependencies to io in app directly, everything works fine.

Do I use the Export/Depends pairs wrong or is my overall layout bad.

I changed the app-and-lib example of Qbs to reflect my layout for clarification.

```
app
|- main.cpp

lib1
|- lib.cpp

lib2
|- lib.cpp
|- Test.h


=== app-and-lib.qbs
import qbs 1.0

Project {
    references: [
        "app/app.qbs",
        "lib1/lib1.qbs",
        "lib2/lib2.qbs"
    ]
}

=== app.qbs
import qbs 1.0

Product {
    type: "application"
    name : "app-and-lib-app"
    files : [ "main.cpp" ]
    Depends { name: "cpp" }
    Depends { name: "lib1" }
}

=== lib1.qbs
import qbs 1.0

Product {
    type: "staticlibrary"
    name: "lib1"
    files: [ "lib.cpp" ]
    cpp.defines: ['CRUCIAL_DEFINE']
    Depends { name: 'cpp' }
    Depends { name: "lib2" }
}

=== lib2.qbs
import qbs 1.0

Product {
    type: "staticlibrary"
    name: "lib2"
    files: [
        "Test.h",
        "lib.cpp",
    ]
    cpp.defines: ['CRUCIAL_DEFINE']
    Depends { name: 'cpp' }

    Export {
      Depends { name: "cpp" }
      cpp.includePaths: "."
    }
}

=== lib.cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Test.h"


#ifndef CRUCIAL_DEFINE
#   error CRUCIAL_DEFINE not defined
#endif

int bla()
{
    puts("Hello World!");
    return 2;
}

=== main.cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Test.h" // Error cannot found Test.h

int bla();
int main()
{
  Test t = new Test();
    return bla();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Went through IRC to Qbs Jira and got the answer from the developers that it is a error in the documentation.
To export dependencies one has to export it, so lib1.qbs needs to be extended like this

```
Exports { 
  Depends { name: "lib2" }
}
```

Follow up: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QBS-928